# “'int' object is not iterable”without int

Tags: python-3.x

What i need to do:
Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target.
Example:

Given nums = [2, 7, 11, 15], target = 9,

Because nums[0] + nums[1] = 2 + 7 = 9,
return [0, 1]

What i did:

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self,nums,target):
        count=0
        i=0
        j=0
        item=0
        result=[]
        self.n=nums
        self.t=target
        count=len(self.n)
        for i in range(0,count):
            for item in range(0,count):
                print(i)
                print(item)
                j=self.n[i]+self.n[item]
                if j==self.t:
                    result=[i,item]
                else:
                    result=0
                    return result            
a = [3,2,4]
b = 6
c=Solution()
print (list(c.twoSum(a,b)))
```

The results:

```
0
0
0
1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test-1213--Twosum-调试1.py", line 24, in <module>
    print (list(c.twoSum(a,b)))
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue here is that result is not always a list, in your first instance you have `result = [i,item]` but in the else: you have it returned as an integer which is not an iterable object in python.  Change your code to this and it should work:

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self,nums,target):
        count=0
        i=0
        j=0
        item=0
        result=[]
        self.n=nums
        self.t=target
        count=len(self.n)
        for i in range(0,count):
            for item in range(0,count):
                print(i)
                print(item)
                j=self.n[i]+self.n[item]
                if j==self.t:
                    result=[i,item]
                else:
                    result=[0]
                    return result            
a = [3,2,4]
b = 6
c=Solution()
print(type(c.twoSum(a,b)))
print (list(c.twoSum(a,b)))
```

Before changing the `result=0` line to `result=[0]` the output of `print(type(c.twoSum(a,b)))` was `<class 'int'>` after adding the list indicator it changes to `<class 'list'>` which is what you were expecting to receive with your `print (list(c.twoSum(a,b)))` statement.

Comment: i delete " else::result=[0]" then everything  is ok.I'm still confused the reason,but thanks!

Comment: That would mean there must be something up with your conditional statements or logic somewhere, I don't know if you want to mark my answer as okay or whether you need more help.

Comment: your answer is ok but most important is your kindness and help!Thanks a lot.